# How to renew the IP with dhcp client if the AP changes the IP range without disassociate the clients

Tags: linux, ip, dhcp, dhclient

We are executing the dhclient for our Wi-Fi interface. 
When the Wi-Fi disassociates from the AP, we have a script that renews the IP automatically from the new AP:

> ```
> cat dhcpaction.sh
> ```

```
#!/bin/sh

IFNAME=$1
CMD=$2

if [ "$CMD" = "CONNECTED" ]; then
    /sbin/dhclient -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf wlan0
fi

if [ "$CMD" = "DISCONNECTED" ]; then
    /sbin/dhclient wlan0 -r
fi
```

The problem is when the dhcp server on the AP(router) changes the IP range, from 192.168.2.X to 192.168.3.X, **without** disassociate the clients, so our device  is not able to know if something changed in the router to force to renew the IP.

Of course, we can set the dhcp-lease-time to 5 min, but this sound bad.

Any solution?

Comment: Why!!?? You shouldn't need to change the network range regularly. When it does just renew the lease on the new range.

Comment: Hi Roaima, this action must be performed automatically. Can we check/execute any file/command to see if the DHCP server changed from that last time?

Comment: How would you detect a wired subnet had changed?

Comment: I don't know... I guess I would have the same problem..